# mock method to do not throw an exception

Tags: java, exception, mocking, mockito

I have method that throws an exception in special circumstances. I would like to write a test case that will check behaviour when exception is not thrown.
I cannot find this in docs or examples. Please help.

E.g.:

```
when(validator.validate(any(ValidationData.class))).thenThrow(new ValidationException());
```

But I would like to test that exception is not thrown at all:

```
class Validator {
    void validate(ValidationData dataToValidate) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

e.g. I need something like:

```
when(doSomething()).thenNotThrowException
```

or

```
when(doSomething()).thenDoNothing
```

Comment: if validator object is mocked then you do not need to anything, if you want validate method to throw exception then only use when-thenThrow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Mockito's mock does nothing for void methods, so you don't need to write anything.

If you want to do this explicitly try this:

`doNothing().when( validator ).validate( any() );`

Comment: Should I use for that a mock, spy, stub?

Comment: Such statement accepts Mockito's mocks and spies, I am not aware of stubs.

Answer (score 0):

To test the case where no exceptions is thrown, you actually need to do even less:

- Do **not** program the `thenThrow` at all
- In your test case, expect the test method to run normally and complete without exceptions (in Junit, don't have any `expected` attribute for `@Test`)

If the test is executed without errors, then your test passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test that there are no exceptions in a test function, you should use this annotation: `@Test(expected = Test.None.class)`

Example:

```
@Test(expected = Test.None.class)
public void testFunction() {
    // some code
}
```